# Fine-uploader using addFiles to upload a file server side

Tags: fine-uploader

In the API documentation it says that addFiles can be called with "An array of Files", I cannot work out how to do this as every time I call it I get this error.

[Fine Uploader 5.11.2] /tmp/file.png is not a valid file container!  Ignoring!

Also to note I did try using an array to pass the files, no luck.
My code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="client/fine-uploader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'server/endpoint.php'
    },
    success: {
        onComplete: "server/endpoint.php?done"
    },
    });

function readFile(filePath){
uploader.addFiles(filePath);
}

var files = ["/tmp/file.png"];

</script>
<script>readFile(files)</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"/tmp/file.png" is a `String`, not a `File`. You must pass either a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), an `<input type="file">` element, or a `<canvas>` element.